# Mutliple lines of a while loop printing in gui dialog (Java)

Tags: java, messagebox

I want to print multiple lines of a while loop in 1 gui dialog box.

This is the code I have currently

```
package Tempconv1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TimesTables 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 0, counter = 0, total = 0; //Declaring Variables
        String str; //String for ShowInputDialog

        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert a number");  //Asks user to input number
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(str); 


            //Calculating number inputs
            while (counter <12)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
                total = counter * num1;
                String multimsg = ("The calculation is " + num1 + " x " + counter + "=" + total);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, multimsg);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Done");
    }


}
```

It works but prints out "The calculation is 5x1 = 5" and then opens a new message box to show "The calculation is 5x2 = 10".
I want it to print out

The Calculation is 5x1 = 5
The Calculation is 5x2 = 10
etc

All inside 1 textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are telling your program to do is create a string of the individual calculation, and then create a dialog box.  Then do it again for each loop.

You will want to build all of the messages into one string inside your loop, and then create the dialog box outside the loop.

```
    String multimsg = "";
    while (counter <12)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        total = counter * num1;
        multimsg += ("The calculation is " + num1 + " x " + counter + "=" + total);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, multimsg);
```

you might want to look into using stringbuilder or similar to be more efficient about building the message string. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Much appreciated, I understand now what I was doing wrong. Think I had just gone code blind from staring at it for so long.
However this only partially worked as it displayed them all on 1 line instead of new lines for each answer.
How could I go about getting it onto each line?

Comment: Ah I figured it out.

I added `"\n"` at the end of the multimsg string so it now reads 

`multimsg += ("The calculation is " + num1 + " x " + counter + "=" + total + "\n");`

and it now takes a new line for each one.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are showing the message inside the `while` loop. The syntax with the `while` loop can be a little bit confusing.

If you are using java 8 you can replace the while/counter with an `IntStream` and you can compose the message by joining the Strings in the collector:

```
String message = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 12)
                          .mapToObj(i -> "The calculation is " + num1 + "x" + i + " = " + i * num1)
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

The first line creates a stream of integers from 1 to 12. The second line maps every number to an individual textmessage. The last line concatenates all the individual messages by joining them with a ,

Your main method would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num1 = 0, counter = 0, total = 0; //Declaring Variables
    String str; //String for ShowInputDialog

    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert a number");  //Asks user to input number
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(str); 


    //Calculating number inputs
    String message = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 12)
                          .mapToObj(i -> "The calculation is " + num1 + "x" + i + " = " + i * num1)
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Done");
```

}

Comment: I am doing it for my university course so they are expecting us to use while loops for it.
My biggest issue is they started us using BlueJ and importing a library that we can only use inside the university so I have had to re-learn what I knew with standard Java Libraries.

But this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see. I would probably still do it with the IntStream and tell the prof that this is a better solution, but I was probably an irritating student so that might be bad advice. At least you are aware now that there are better tools than using that while loop. You can always show appreciation by upvoting an answer that helped you. As for the libraries, seems this code snippet is at least all standard Java.

Answer (score -1):

before loop:`String multimsg = "";`

in loop after the maths:`multimsg=multimsg+"The calculation is " + num1 + " x " + counter + "=" + total;`
and after while loop `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, multimsg);`

Answer (score -1):

Build only the msg inside the loop and save it to StringBuilder.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num1 = 0, counter = 0, total = 0; //Declaring Variables
    String str; //String for ShowInputDialog

    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert a number");  //Asks user to input number
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(str); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Calculating number inputs
    while (counter <12)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        total = counter * num1;
        sb.append("The calculation is ").append(num1).append(" x ").append(counter).append("=").append(total).append(" ");

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Done");
}
```

Comment: This also only partially worked as it displayed them all on 1 line instead of new lines for each answer. How could I go about getting it onto each line?

Didn't know about stringbuilder so thanks for giving me an example of how it works.